# add blank attribute in magento backend and use php to calculate the value

Tags: php, magento, attributes

i have added a new atribute called frontend_price in magento's backend in the manage product selection.

In the value of this attribute would like to get the product's price and multiply it with the Vat tax and the currency. Nothing fancy just to se the product's frontend price in the backend, but not stored into any table of the db.
This attribute is for internal porpose only, so it does not have to be visible in the frontend.

i was thinking of :

```
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND,Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);
$currencyrate = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate(); 
$price_normal = $_product->getPrice();
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('frontend_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) = $price_normal*$currencyrate*1.24;
```

Unfortunatly i don't know where to implement this code to see it in the backend.
Any ideea where to edit the page for the backend product selection page.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have added that attribute under manage product?

Comment: did it but i have no ideea where to implement the code for the backend

Comment: whether you have add that attribute by programmatically or by using manage attributes/

Comment: i have added it by manage attributes

Comment: just like i said in the description it's for internal use only and it has to be calculated on the fly by php

Comment: to explain my self better .. my store is in another language, the frontend currency is in lei and the base currency is in euro

Comment: you can set it by  "$product->setFprice($price);" on list.phtml file.

Comment: so i want a field ( attribute ) in the backend , in the product page info to show the frontend price ( witch has currency exchange, tax calculation etc .. )

Comment: Fprice is the name of that attribute. $price is the final price. When you run that list page, Final price will be set of those products in to backend

Comment: where would i find list.phtml

Comment: design/frontend/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: it the frontend ? that's wierd ... i'l try ( i would magento to do this calculation for the admin user in the backend, not for the customer in the frontend

Comment: its for only calculating those price for corresponding products. There we only do calculation. we have to set it to that attribute after getting Final price]

Comment: in the backend the Pret_magazin attribute is still blank